How to make infinite download progress for stream file from ASP.NET Core to Chrome browser
I have ASP.NET Core endpoint which streams dynamically created file of unknown size:
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExportAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        Response.Headers.Append("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
        Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        Response.Headers.Append("Pragma", "no-cache");
        Response.Headers.Append("Expires", "0");
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.Headers.Append("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.zip\"");

        PipeWriter outStream = HttpContext.Response.BodyWriter;
        
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        ReadOnlyMemory<byte> source = new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            await outStream.WriteAsync(source, cancellationToken);
            await outStream.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);
            await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);
        }

        return new EmptyResult();
    }

It somehow works, the file is streamed to the browser, nevertheless I cannot see any progress unless the entire file is downloaded to the browser. I understand that without content length sent I can hardly see exact progress, but I expect to see at least that infinite animation that download is happening. In Chrome developer tools I can see that the file is streamed, so Chromes is aware about the stream. The pipeline is HTTP2.
Why there is no download animation at all?

How are you hitting the action? Just the browser address bar? Or using an ajax request?

In developer tools I see XHR request

You are right, hitting the request into address bar solved the problem. Thanks.

not an answer, but you can simplify this by returning file: ex:   return File(memory, mimetype, filename);  It will automatically stream it.

As everyone suggests you can directly hit the endpoint in the browser which will show you the download progress or another option is you could use the client side code to set the custom progress bar for the downloading file something like below:
ExportController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace DownloadProgressDemo.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ExportController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("download")]
        public async Task ExportAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Response.Headers.Append("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
            Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            Response.Headers.Append("Pragma", "no-cache");
            Response.Headers.Append("Expires", "0");
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            Response.Headers.Append("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.zip\"");

            // Create a zip archive in memory
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    // Add files to the zip archive
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
                    {
                        var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry($"file{i}.txt");
                        using (var entryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
                        {
                            await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync($"This is content for file {i}.");
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Set the Content-Length header
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                Response.Headers.ContentLength = memoryStream.Length;

                // Stream the zip file to the client
                await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(Response.Body, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
}

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>File Download with Progress Bar and Percentage</title>
    <style>
        /* Minimalist progress bar style */
        #progressContainer {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #f3f3f3;
            position: relative;
            height: 5px;
            display: none; /* Hidden initially */
        }

        #progressBar {
            width: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #4caf50;
            transition: width 0.2s;
        }

        #progressText {
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            display: none; /* Hidden initially */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Download File with Progress Bar and Percentage</h1>
    <button onclick="downloadFile()">Download File</button>
    <div id="progressContainer">
        <div id="progressBar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="progressText">0%</div>
    <p id="status"></p>

    <script>
        async function downloadFile() {
            const progressContainer = document.getElementById('progressContainer');
            const progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
            const progressText = document.getElementById('progressText');
            const status = document.getElementById('status');

            progressContainer.style.display = 'block';  // Show progress bar
            progressText.style.display = 'block';  // Show progress percentage text

            try {
                // Start the download
                const response = await fetch('/api/export/download');
                if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Network response was not ok');

                const reader = response.body.getReader();
                const contentLength = +response.headers.get('Content-Length');

                let receivedLength = 0;
                const chunks = [];

                progressBar.style.width = '0%';  // Reset progress bar
                progressText.textContent = '0%'; // Reset percentage text

                // Read the data in chunks and update the progress bar and percentage text
                while (true) {
                    const { done, value } = await reader.read();
                    if (done) break;

                    chunks.push(value); // Accumulate chunks
                    receivedLength += value.length;

                    // Update progress bar and percentage based on download progress
                    if (contentLength) {
                        const percent = Math.floor((receivedLength / contentLength) * 100);
                        progressBar.style.width = `${percent}%`;
                        progressText.textContent = `${percent}%`; // Display percentage
                    }
                }

                // Create a Blob from the accumulated chunks and trigger file download
                const blob = new Blob(chunks);
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = url;
                a.download = 'file.zip';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();

                // Cleanup
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                a.remove();

                status.textContent = 'Download complete!';
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Download error:', error);
                status.textContent = 'Download failed.';
            } finally {
                // Hide progress bar and percentage text after download is complete or on error
                setTimeout(() => {
                    progressContainer.style.display = 'none';
                    progressBar.style.width = '0%';  // Reset for future downloads
                    progressText.style.display = 'none';
                    progressText.textContent = '0%'; // Reset for future downloads
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

